# Interpretation of Mass Continuity Equation in MHD

Tags: mass, conservation-laws, magnetohydrodynamics

I'm writing up my final-year dissertation and I'm required to give, as part of the introduction, an analysis of all the equations (and their terms) of which I use. Embarrassingly, whilst of course understanding  the principle of mass continuity, I'm not quite sure about the physical interpretation of each of the terms, $A$ and $B$.

$$\underbrace{\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}}_{\text{A}} + \underbrace{\nabla \cdot (\rho \textbf{v})}_{\text{B}} = 0$$

I mean, I know $A$ is the change in density w\r\t time and $B$ is the  divergence (flux density) of the density $\times$ the velocity, but I don't think that's quite enough, if you follow. Any help/guidance or reading resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi see this http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172813/

Comment: As I linked in the above proposed duplicate, you might want to also look at my answer to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138552) and some of the answers [to this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109533).

Comment: Also: what is it about the mass continuity equation that is troubling you as compared to the momentum and energy conservation equations?